# How to trace the Api Proxy requests without using the Test console on API Gateway?

Tags: azure-api-management

I would like to trace real-time requests coming to my API Proxy in azure. There is a facility to trace using the Test console on the API Gateway as per the article below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector

But I would like to trace the request when clients sending from their applications or when sending requests from POSTMAN.

There is a similar facility in Apigee Edge to enable the trace at runtime.

Does anyone have idea how to trace realtime API Proxy Requests?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable Azure doagnostocs and use Azure monitor.

Check the below for how to and what data will be logged.

Please look at the below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor#diagnostic-logs

Comment: My pleasure, Can you please accept the answer if it was helpful.